# Return jquery-ui widget from function

Tags: coffeescript, jquery-ui-widget-factory

I have a requirement wherein i need to return a widget instance from a coffeescript class method.

```
class Chart
    constructor: (@chartData) ->
    getChartType: ->
        @chartData.type
    getChartTitle: ->
        @chartData.title
    getChart: (context,ClickCallback) ->
        #Need to create a chart widget instance and return
```

From the calling function i just want to do something like this

```
Chart c = new Chart(data)
object = c.getChart(@,@._onSeriesClick)
@.element.object()
```

Am I doing it the correct way? Is it possible to return a widget from a function or do i need to pass the element and initialize the widget within my coffeescript class?

Answer (score 0):

When calling any function as `new func(...)` it will:

1. Create new empty object
2. Pass this new empty object as `this` to the function
3. Function then can modify `this` as needed (`contructor` will add methods and `chartData` to `this`)
4. If there are no explicit `return` statements - modified `this` object will be returned.

In case of CoffeeScript - it's better to leave things as they are: return an object of "class" Chart (keep in mind that "class" here is just a fancy name for convenience) and create a widget as you did in a object field.